# What was "primitive labor rent" or "mains mortales"?

Tags: middle-ages, russia

In this quote from Hellie, R. (1971) *Enserfment and military change in Muscovy*, Chicago, USA, page 14 ([archive.org](https://archive.org/details/enserfmentmilita0000hell/page/14)):

> B. D. Grekov, in periodizing peasant history, offered the following three forms of exploitative relationships as successively characterizing recorded pre-Petrine Russian history: (1) primitive labor rent, similar to French *mains mortales*, from the middle of the first millennium A.D. to about the twelfth century...

What was "primitive labor rent" or "*mains mortales*"?

Comment: failing to include the comparisons from the source text limits the extent to which people can respond.  Hellie has a comparison in mind, and failing to include the comparison limits people who are willing to deep search JSTOR.

Comment: Why did you remove my link to the text? https://archive.org/details/enserfmentmilita0000hell/page/14

Comment: I like the question; I couldn't find an easy definition for the term, so I'm grateful to @martin for the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Including all three phases:

(1) Primitive labour rent: the serf owed his lord some number of days labour usually in the lord's fields.
(2) Rent paid in kind: the serf owed his lord some of the serf's produce.  This might be so much corn or meat each year.
(3) Rent paid in cash plus a considerable amount of corvée: the serf had to obtain some cash from trading his produce as well as some enforced labour (corvée).

This is a fairly normal development over the centuries that the feudal system operated.  Labour becomes payment in kind instead of labour, which in turn becomes cash as the amount of cash in use increases.

Samuel Russel is right that you should include full quotes, it helps to understand the commentators stance.  The link is also important since it is not paywalled and can be easily read.

Comment: This would be an excellent answer with a citation or two.